# Swap rows and columns in SQL without knowing the schema

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dbt

I have to parse a raw table (written in JSON) into something "clean". I'm doing it with Spark-SQL. The raw data is all messed up, as you will see. I will provide some ***simplified* examples** to make it easier.

This is the raw JSON object:

```json
{
   "user_1":{
      "user_name":"Andy",
      "user_lastname":"Martins",
      "user_accounts":{
         "facebook":"https://...",
         "twitter":[
            "https://...",
            "https://..."
         ]
      }
   },
   "user_2":{
      "user_name":"Joe",
      "user_lastname":"Foo",
      "user_accounts":{
         "twitter":"https://",
         "stack_overflow":"https://..."
      }
   }
}
```

Reading it with Spark produces the following result:

```scala
val df = spark
    .read
    .option("multiline", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "false")
    .format("json").load("data.json")

df.show(false)
// +----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
// |user_1                                                    |user_2                             |
// +----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
// |{{https://..., [https://..., https://...]}, Martins, Andy}|{{https://..., https://}, Foo, Joe}|
// +----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

**I want something like this:**

```
+-------+---------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------+-------------+
|user_id|user_name|user_lastname|fb_account   |tw_account                |so_account   |
+-------+---------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------+-------------+
|user_1 |Andy     |Martins      |"https://..."|["https://...","https://..|             |
|user_2 |Joe      |Foo          |             |"https://..."             |"https://..."|
+-------+---------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------+-------------+
```

---

As you can see, identifiers are gathered as column names and the rest of the object is identified as a single thing. Here come multiple problems:

#### 1. How do I transpose columns into individual rows, without knowing the column names?

I've tried to use the table's schema, but this is not feasible when having hundreds of thousands (even millions) of elements (as in my case).

```scala
spark.sql("DESCRIBE df").createOrReplaceTempView("desc")
val column_names = spark.sql("SELECT col_name FROM desc").collect() // <- Not feasible with 1M+ columns

column_names.foreach(c => {
  val column_name = c.toString.substring(1, c.toString.length -1)
  spark.sql(f"SELECT stack(1, '${column_name}', `${column_name}`) AS (`user_id`, `data`) FROM df").show(false)
  }
)
```

#### 2. How do I merge tables without the same schema?

Even if I find a way to do the previous thing, I wonder how I could join both tables to be a single one. As you can see below, schemas are different:

```
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|user_id|data                                                      |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|user_1 |{{https://..., [https://..., https://...]}, Martins, Andy}|
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------+

+-------+-----------------------------------+
|user_id|data                               |
+-------+-----------------------------------+
|user_2 |{{https://..., https://}, Foo, Joe}|
+-------+-----------------------------------+

root
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- user_accounts: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- facebook: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- twitter: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- user_lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- user_name: string (nullable = true)

root
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- user_accounts: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- stack_overflow: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- twitter: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- user_lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- user_name: string (nullable = true)
```

###### a) I can not run `UNION ALL` on them to be in the same table:

```
u1.unionAll(u2)

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types. struct<user_accounts:struct<stack_overflow:string,twitter:string>,user_lastname:string,user_name:string> <> struct<user_accounts:struct<facebook:string,twitter:array<string>>,user_lastname:string,user_name:string> at the second column of the second table;
'Union false, false
:- Project [user_id#113, data#114]
:  +- Generate stack(1, user_1, user_1#0), false, [user_id#113, data#114]
:     +- SubqueryAlias df
:        +- Relation[user_1#0,user_2#1] json
+- Project [user_id#117, data#118]
   +- Generate stack(1, user_2, user_2#1), false, [user_id#117, data#118]
      +- SubqueryAlias df
         +- Relation[user_1#0,user_2#1] json
```

###### b) Schemas are unpredictable

I used [dbt](https://docs.getdbt.com/) to try to simplify it a bit with macros and Jinja.

First, I tried to cast all necessary fields to have the same schema in all the tables, but that's not something I like, having everything as an string when there can be arrays.

```sql
{% for column in column_names %}
    tmp_pivoted_data_{{ loop.index }} AS (
        SELECT stack(1, '{{column}}', `{{column}}`) AS (`user_id`, `data`)
        FROM jsons
    ),
    tmp_data_{{ loop.index }} AS (
        SELECT `user_id`,
                `data`.`get_dns_info`.`timestamp` AS `timestamp`,
                string(`data`.`user_name`) AS `user_name`,
                string(`data`.`user_lastname`) AS `user_lastname`,
                string(`data`.`user_accounts`.`facebook`) AS `fb_account`,
                string(`data`.`user_accounts`.`twitter`) AS `tw_account`,
                string(`data`.`user_accounts`.`stack_overflow`) AS `so_account`
                
        FROM tmp_pivoted_data_{{ loop.index }}
    )
    {% if not loop.last %}
    ,
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

I also tried to *conditionally cast*, depending on the data type of the column (again, using the `DESCRIBE TABLE` above). But I realized that using a `CASE WHEN / ELSE` requires all the cases to return the same data type.

Comment: Do you have to import exactly that JSON into a df/table, or can you do a preprocessing step? Is it small enough to fit into memory?

Comment: @tconbeer Right now it's about 1Tb of JSON data, currently split into small JSON files. The dataset is supposed to keep growing, and (probably) have bigger files in the future.